# RedCaptcha After 3 failed three Attempts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

May be This questions have been asked previously but i haven't found it on `MVC` context.

i have implemented it with the help of [How to add `ReCaptcha` to your Asp.Net MVC4 register form](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-your-asp-net-mvc4-register-form)

`ReCaptcha` need to be rendered after three failed attempt. but to render it, shall it requires a new Partial view, or its good to go with same view. if same view ,what modification are required. may be i sound stupid but that's how we learn things .

Answer (score 0):

You can add counter in your ViewModel that you increment for each failed attempt.

Then, in your View, you can choose to display the control, for example if you are using the Microsoft.Web.Helpers:

```
@if (model.counter > 3)
{
   @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "white")
}
```